# How to save changes to WPF datagrid showing data form 2 joined tables?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have 2 tables:

```
Person:
    p_id  
    p_name  
    c_id  
Car:  
    c_id  
    c_name
```

Here is my XAML tag:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myPath}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

And here is the C#:

```
a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT p.p_name AS Person, c.c_name AS Car FROM Person AS p, Car AS c WHERE p.c_id = c.c_id", c);
d = new DataSet();
a.Fill(d, "myPath");
dataGrid.DataContext = d;
```

Sure I can view but I cannot edit the data. I hope by some "Magic" I can turn the Car-TextColumn into a `ComboBox` with the Item list from the `Car` table.

Sorry if this question was asked, this is the first time I am trying C# and WPF, not sure what keywords to search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `DataTemplates` for this. You can hook `AutoGeneratingColumn` and provide there your logic. Also you may have to load `Cars` separatly to show them in `ComboBox` because might not be loaded all possible cars after executing your query. 

And I strongly recommend to take a look into `MVVM` pattern.

---

There are couple similar questions that might help you with this:

- [Binding WPF DataGrid to DataTable using
  TemplateColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns)
- [How to bind a table in a dataset to a WPF datagrid in C# and
  XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511177/how-to-bind-a-table-in-a-dataset-to-a-wpf-datagrid-in-c-sharp-and-xaml)
- [WPF DataGrid Practical
  Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and add a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` like this -

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.PropertyName == "CustomerID")
  {
    DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();

    column.DataFieldBinding = new Binding("CustomerID");

    column.DataFieldTarget = ComboBoxDataFieldTarget.SelectedValue;

    column.ItemsSource = DBAccess.GetCustomers().Tables["Customers"].DefaultView;

    column.EditingElementStyle = (Style)this.RootGrid.FindResource("CustomerFKStyle");

    e.Column = column;
  }
}
```

refer this article for details and sample - [WPF DataGrid: Working with DataGridComboBoxColumn CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/26/wpf-datagrid-working-with-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx)