# edit/view postgresql table in C# wpf app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, postgresql

I need to create a means of viewing and editing a postgresql table through C# WPF style app.  Is it possible to do this in a DataGrid control?  So far I found a class in the .NET framework called SqlDataAdapter, which can return a query result in a DataSet object, and update the data in db appropriately if the DataSet is altered.  But I think this is only for Microsoft Sequel Server.  Would this work for PostgreSql?  And would it be possible to bind the DataSet to a Datagrid?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) is what I have always used. It uses the same interfaces so instead of a `SqlDataAdapter` you'll have an `NpgsqlDataAdapter` that functions the same way. From there, you can populate your `DataTable` or `DataSource` and bind that to your `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using Npgsql and did not think to look there.  Can the DataTable and DataSource objects be bound to a DataGrid in WPF?  I found examples of this, but they were for System.Windows.Forms based controls.

Comment: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns) [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511177/how-to-bind-a-table-in-a-dataset-to-a-wpf-datagrid-in-c-sharp-and-xaml)